# How do I use a constant in Rust's inline assembly macro?

Tags: rust, inline-assembly, arm64

I'm porting some legacy assembly code to Rust and I need to call it through the `asm!` macro. However, the assembly code depends on some constants stored in a C header file. I'd like to keep it similar, define the constants in Rust and have the names of the constants in the `asm` macro.

Legacy C header:

```
#define HCR_VALUE 0xffff0000
```

Legacy ASM file:

```
.func
...
ldr    x0, =HCR_VALUE
...
```

Rust code:

```
pub const HCR_VALUE: u32 = 0xffff0000;
```

```
unsafe { asm!("ldr x0, HCR_VALUE":::"x0"); }
```

Building the application ends up with a linker error:

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: HCR_VALUE
```

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that a Rust compiler has no reason to emit a line of asm like `.equ HCR_VALUE, 0xffff0000` to define that name as an assemble-time constant.  Think of inline asm as just letting you put your own stuff into the compiler's asm output before it's fed to an assembler; the template string is *not* understood by the compiler other than to substitute `%0` or `%[operand_name]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the constant with a suitable constraint, like this:

```
unsafe { asm!("ldr x0, =${0:c}" : : "i" (HCR_VALUE) : "x0"); }
```

The right constraint depends on the architecture; on RISC CPUs, not all constants can be represented as immediate values.  So you may have to use a register constraint instead and have LLVM materialize the constant there.

Comment: Thanks @Florian. This is definitely the right direction. I tried as you suggested and got the following error: `<inline asm>:11:16: error: expected label or encodable integer pc offset
    ldr    x0, -453`

Comment: I don't have Rust or arm (`ldr` looks like arm), but you could try:  `asm!("ldr x0, $0":: "i" (HCR_VALUE):"x0");` or `asm!("ldr x0, =$0":: "i" (HCR_VALUE):"x0");`

Comment: @phodina Sorry, you still need to put the `=` into the inline assembly, like David said.

Comment: Thanks @Florian and @David. Putting `=` does the trick. Sorry for not saying it's an AArch64 instruction.

Answer (score 3):

The current answers `asm` style was deprecated in favor of a more rustacean syntax. However, constants in assembly are still behind a feature flag and only in nightly if I recall correctly. Just add `#![feature(asm_const)]` at the top of your main file to use this amazing feature.

```rs
pub const HCR_VALUE: u32 = 0xffff0000;
// just assume we are in an unsafe block
asm!(
  "ldr x0, ={hcr}",
  "...",

  hcr = const HCR_VALUE,
  // this is technically necessary to tell the compiler that you have 
  // changed the value of x0 in your assembly code (called clobbering)
  out ("x0") _ 
);
```

More information can be found in [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93332)

You normally don't want to use `ldr` with a const operand in inline asm: more normally you'd ask the compiler for the constant already in a register if you want that.  Then you don't need to mark it as an `out` register, and the compiler will know about that value still being in a register after the asm statement. In a very large asm statement you might run out of registers, or in a `naked` function the compiler won't emit instructions for you.

In instructions like `"orr x1, x2, #{hcr}"` (hard-coded registers) or `and {foo}, {bar}, #{hcr}` (compiler's choice of registers) it makes sense to use `HCR_VALUE` directly as an immediate with boolean instructions.  (Bitwise boolean instructions use a bit-pattern encoding for immediates that can encode constants with one contiguous block of set bits, or a repeating pattern, so `0xffff0000` is usable directly, unlike `0xffef0000` or similar.)

---

When you want the value in a register, preferably ask the compiler to do it before your asm instructions:

```rs
asm!(
  "use {reg} here where you would have used x0", 
  reg = in(reg) HCR_VALUE
);
```

This will probably result in the same compiled result as above.

If you want to put a value in a specific register, you can:

```rs
asm!(
  "...", // You don't even have to alter your code
  in ("x0") HCR_VALUE
);
```

Comment: For a short asm statement, you'd want to ask the compiler to put the constant in a register for you.  You'd only want an `ldr` (or in this case `mov` (or `orr` with `wzr`) for that constant on AArch64) if you needed to re-materialize the constant in a register inside a loop after destroying it, or something like that.  *That's* the real way to translate `ldr    x0, =HCR_VALUE` to inline asm, by hoisting that instruction out of the asm statement itself and letting the compiler do it.

Comment: But IDK how to express that in Rust asm; in GNU C inline asm it would be `register uint32_t HCR_VALUE asm("x0") = 0xffff0000;` / `asm("..." : : [HCRV] "r"(HCR_VALUE));`  Or let the compiler pick its choice of register, instead of using `register ... asm` to force `"r"` to pick `x0`, if your asm template can just as easily use `%[HCRV]` instead of hard-coded or implicit `x0`.

Comment: Good update, would +1 again if I could.  Using an actual `hcr = const HCR_VALUE` input (similar to GNU C `"i"` input) would be useful if you can use it as an immediate (e.g. with `and` or `orr x1, x1, {hcr}`) without needing it in a register.  So there is a use-case for that, but it usually doesn't involve `ldr`.  If you have time, updating the examples accordingly, that might be useful to people learning inline asm basics.

Comment: I didn't really think about the exact asm code the first time. Obviously, you wouldn't want to load a `const` in like this if you could make Rust do it for you. It's more about the general idea. Should I rather replace the `ldr` with an `and` or an `orr` in the asnwer?

Comment: Also, you are probably like the second friendly guy I met on SO, lol

Comment: Actually, I just thought about something. There is a good reason to use constants in `ldr`: Expecially, when you have a huge `asm!`-block, you might have too many constants to load to fit in all registers at once. Or you only want to use one register in one block but with several constants.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251215/discussion-between-hacker-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: Yes, register pressure is one of the few reasons you might `ldr` a constant in a large asm statement.  If I was answering this from scratch, I might still start with answering what the OP asked for, with another instruction in the same template showing using it as an immediate constant for other instructions, in this case bitwise due to the form of the constant.  With a comment in the code block mentioning that `ldr` not what you normally want.  Then lay it out like you've done, with `reg = in(reg) HCR_VALUE` and then the explicit-register version.

Comment: I meant `asm!( "ldr x0, ={hcr}" // rare use-case`
  `,"orr x1, x2, #{hcr}" //  common use-case`.  I think you broke your other examples by using `{reg}` as the destination of an `ORR` while telling the compiler it was an `in` operand.  Also, AArch64 `orr` is a 3-operand instruction.  See https://godbolt.org/z/q4W3Gbove for compiler output using ORR with this immediate operand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can just write `orr x1, x2` and it automatically expands to `orr x1, x1, x2`

Comment: I think, I don't really like changing the example too much to make it more useful. Because then you have to add a lot of code that isn't really related to the question (like handling with the registers that changed).

Comment: Ok, well you still can't write an `in` operand without telling the compiler about it, and using some arbitrary ORR constant like `#0x10` is not at all what I was talking about.  I meant to use `#{hcr}` as the immediate, since that's a reason you'd want it as a constant **instead of** in a register.

Comment: Fair point about having to write `out` operand constraints, but you already missed doing that for `x0` in your initial example (which writes it using `ldr`) or any of the later asm blocks.  Earlier some of them didn't need any output constraints because they only asked the compiler to put a value in a register outside the asm template string.